# Pandas cx_Oracle - Insert failing

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sql-insert, cx-oracle

I have this code to use cx_oracle to insert data to a table, but getting some error.

My data looks like this:

```
[['BOB', 20190619, 118.16, 118.38, 116.05, 117.8, 'No', 117.8, 117.8, 117.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

My attempts at the code is this:

```
sql='INSERT INTO stockstats VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16)'

n = 0
for i in df.iterrows():
  cursor_1.execute(sql,df_list[n])
  n += 1

cursor_1.execute(sql,df_list[n])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I also tried this, and get the same issue:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO stockstats VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16)'
cursor_1.executemany(sql, df.values.tolist())

cursor_1.executemany(sql, df.values.tolist())
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Was wondering what I was doing wrong.

Any hep would be great.

Comment: can you share the `df`. It's not clear that you have columns or rows from your data. Btw, there are 17 comma-seperated elements within the data, but 16 bind variables for the table.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities for you to investigate:

- make sure that all of the rows have the same number of columns (by printing the length prior to calling execute())
- check the list of bind names that cx_Oracle thinks exist by calling `cursor.prepare(sql)` followed by `cursor.bindnames()`

Both of these checks should help discover the source of the issue -- whether a typo or "bad" input data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you have within the dataframe `df` whether they're columns or rows. Even if you consider them as columns, the number of comma-seperated elements(**17**) does not conform to the number of bind variables(**16**) within the `VALUES` list of the `sql` string.

Considering as a regular insertion from a dataframe along with those comma-seperated elements as columns, fixing the number of columns depending on the number of column of the table, prefer using ***df.to_sql*** with connection through use of ***sqlalchemy.create_engine*** during the insertion such as

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://un:pwd@dbhost:port/dbname')
conn = engine.connect()

try:
    df.to_sql('stockstats', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False )
    engine.execute("SELECT * FROM stockstats").fetchall()
```

against issues due to ***`NaN`*** values